# Tarski's axiom implies a proper class of inaccessible cardinals

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

I'm trying to prove this theorem, but is it even true? A *Tarski's class* is a set $T$ such that:

- For each $y\in T$, ${\cal P}(y)\subseteq T$ and ${\cal P}(y)\in T$, and
- for each $A\subseteq T$ such that $A\prec T$ (a.k.a. $A$ is strictly smaller than $T$), $A\in T$.

Tarski's axiom says that for each set $x$, there is a Tarski's class $T\ni x$. I have managed to prove that $V_\kappa$ is a Tarski's class iff $\kappa$ is (strongly) inaccessible, but I don't think this is sufficient to prove that there is a proper class of inaccessibles, because I don't have any control over the form of the Tarski's classes that arise from the axiom. One reasonable way of wrangling the form of the Tarski's classes is to define the function $T(x)=\bigcap\{T\mid x\in T\wedge T\mbox{ is a Tarski's class}\}$, which is well-defined given Tarski's axiom and is a Tarski's class because Tarski's classes are closed under arbitrary intersection.

The only step that remains is to prove that $T(x)=V_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the least inaccessible with $\kappa>{\rm rank}(x)$, but I'm at a loss for how to approach the problem. Any tips?

Comment: For what it's worth, [this MO answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102846/whats-the-difference-between-zfcgrothendieck-zfcinaccessible-cardinals-and-ta/102849#102849) proves that the cardinality of any Tarski class is an inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: @Miha That is exactly what I'm looking for; thanks for the link. I did have an extra question though to perhaps make this not just a duplicate: in the accepted answer, they somehow construct a family of $\kappa^{{\rm cf}(\kappa)}$ sets in the Tarski's class $T$. (1) I didn't quite understand the construction; can someone explain that step? (2) Is there a way to avoid Konig's theorem, which is an AC equivalent? Since $T$ is well-orderable, I was hoping I could avoid it.

Comment: I also wanted to remark that on that page and also [this other one](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28389/about-grothendieck-universe-and-tarskis-a-and-a-axioms), people say that if there is an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, then ${\cal P}^\kappa(\{\{x\}\})$ is a Tarski's class for any $x$, so there is a proper class of Tarski's classes. In fact, it is not necessary to assume any inaccessibles, because ${\cal P}^\omega(\{\{x\}\})$ is also a Tarski's class.

Comment: Note: when I said I wanted to avoid AC, I meant in the "local" implication that if $T$ is a Tarski's class, then $|T|$ is inaccessible. Of course if we assume Tarski's axiom, then AC is provable, so it is not necessary to avoid AC in the proof of a proper class of inaccessibles.

Comment: Regarding the $\kappa^{\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)}$ many sets, this is the number of subsets of $T$ of size $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$. If we assume $\kappa$ is singular then all of these will be elements of $T$. As for avoiding AC, I'll think about it, although I have very little intuition about what can and can't be done without choice.

Comment: @MihaHabič That was my first thought, but I wasn't sure what was the way he was choosing the subsets, or if he meant all of them (do you have a reference for the proof of the formula for infinite cardinal binomial coefficients?). I later realized that the *set* $\kappa^{{\rm cf}(\kappa)}$ is literally embedded in $T$, since each such function $f:{\rm cf}(\kappa)\to\kappa$ is a set of ordered pairs from $T$ (note that $\kappa\subseteq T$) of size ${\rm cf}(\kappa)<\kappa$, so each $f\in T$ and thus $\kappa^{\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)}\subseteq T$.

Comment: I agree with your argument. Regarding the formula for the number of subsets, if $|X|=\kappa\geq\lambda$, it is easy to see that $\kappa^\lambda\leq |[X]^\lambda|$. On the other hand, given a subset $A\subseteq X$ of size $\lambda$, you can assign to it some function $f\colon \lambda\to X$ with range $A$. This shows $|[X]^\lambda|\leq\kappa^\lambda$.

Comment: @MihaHabič I'm not sure I agree with your "easy to see" claim that $[\kappa]^\lambda\ge\kappa^\lambda$. By analogy to finite combinatorics, the set of 1-1 functions $\lambda\to\kappa$ modulo an ordering of $\lambda$ is clearly a quotient of a subset of the set of all functions $\lambda\to\kappa$, so I can be convinced that $[\kappa]^\lambda\le\kappa^\lambda$ (where $[\kappa]^\lambda=\{x\in{\cal P}(\kappa)\mid|x|=\lambda\}$), but the reverse relation is not at all obvious to me. (Also, you've been very helpful and I managed to complete the proof, so if you could put an answer I'll accept.)

Comment: Any function $f\colon \lambda\to\kappa$ is a subset of $\lambda\times\kappa$ of size $\lambda$. Since $\kappa\geq\lambda$, it can be coded as a subset of $\kappa$ of size $\lambda$.